# Why parsing error for Math.mod() in conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is my code :

```
{this.state.tabledata.map(item,number => {
return (
    {(Math.mod(number,2)==0)?(  //Here parsing error
    <div
    style={{ padding: "2px",marginBottom:'5px',backgroundColor:'lightgray' }}
    class="panel panel-default"
    >
    ):(
    <div
    style={{ padding: "2px",marginBottom:'5px' }}
    class="panel panel-default"
    >
    )}

    <div
        class="panel-heading"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
    >
        ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div className="row">
        ....
    </div>
    </div>
);
})}
```

In parsing error line also,

I tried `number%2===0` but got the same error.

Thank you.

let me know if any problem while understanding.

Comment: `Math.mod` is not a javascript function, modulus operator is `%`.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.mod` is not a js function, you should use `%`. Beside, you need to wrap the arguments of map function into `()`. Try with:

```
{this.state.tabledata.map((item, number) => {
  return (
      {number % 2 === 0  ? (
      // rest of your code here
```